# AWS reserved instance multiple EC2 running at the same time

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If I have 2 equal EC2 instances running simultaneously for 12 h a day and I have only 1 reserved instance, does this reserved instance cover the cost of both instances since the sum of daily hours is 24h? Or however, since the 2 works simultaneously, would not the reserved one cover me and would they apply extra expenses? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

According to this document from rackspace, you would be billed for 1 reserved instance, and 1 on-demand instance when it is running:

> Example 4: Oversubscribing your Reserved Instances for half the time:
>   Assume that you have purchased 2 Reserved Instances. You decide to
>   launch 4 instances for only 12 hours per day, and Terminate or Stop
>   them for the other 12 hours. In this scenario, you will be charged an
>   additional 24 hours (12 hours x 2 instances) at the On-Demand rate, as
>   you already have 2 instances consuming your Reserved Instance
>   reservations and any additional instances running at the same time are
>   charged at the On-Demand rate. You cannot store unused Reserved
>   Instance hours and use them to oversubscribe at other times. If you
>   have workloads that need predictable scaled capacity, you may consider
>   want to consider a purchase of Scheduled Reserved instances instead:
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-scheduled-instances.html

from: https://manage.rackspace.com/aws/docs/product-guide/reserved_instances.html